# Make materials uneditable & inapplicable

Tags: materials

I'm going to publish a model, wich contains certain materials. The problem is that I wouldn't like people to use the materials for their own use once I publish my file. Is there any way I could make materials uneditable, and inapplicable for other mesh that isn't the one that alredy has it?

Thanks!

Comment: Bake the object

Comment: No, there is not, it goes against the "open philosophy" of the Blender community. If you don't want people to edit your materials don't publish them with your model

Comment: Best thing you can do is include a license for how people can use the materials.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, you can hide some of the complexity in the material by baking stuff to textures, but this isn't possible for everything.

Blender offers techinical no way of doing stuff like this, in part because it is against the ideology which drives blender (Open Source) and in part because for digital stuff it is pretty much impossible. Consider how much effort the entertainment industry spends to try and create technical solutions to digital piracy, and still they get broken.

There are however legal solutions, you could release you work under a 'No Derivative Works' license (I believe there is a variant of creative commons for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_Commons_license).

Answer (score 2):

Publish without the materials, or with a basic material and a uv mapped baked image from the materials. There is no way to really keep anyone form using the materials, even if it is a licensing issue - a person only need understand what you are doing with your materials and replicate to some extent with their own variation and the materials are no longer 'yours'. If your model relies heavily on textures, offer it with reduced resolution versions so that they are not as easy to just apply to other models unless you are selling the model - then all the materials and textures becomes a selling point.